# IPv6 hierarchical routing

Tags: routing, ipv6

I'm trying to set up IPv6 for my small office.  My ISP have a router in the building and the individual businesses are hooked up via ethernet to that. They told me to connect to the gateway 2001:db8:300:200::1/56 (not the real address). I can successfully ping this and connect to internet sites via IPv6 if I plug my laptop directly into the wall.

I tried to set up a Cisco RV160W router as follows:

1. WAN interface IP 2001:db8:300:200::2/64, default gateway 2001:db8:300:200::1
2. LAN interface IP 2001:db8:300:201::1/64

This results in an auto generated routing table like so:

```
Destination             Next hop             Hop count    Interface
2001:db8:300:200::/64   ::                   256          WAN
2001:db8:300:201::/64   ::                   256          LAN
::/0                    2001:db8:300:200::1  768          WAN
```

It all looks good to me, but I can't ping the ISP gateway 2001:db8:300:200::1 from my laptop. I can ping both interfaces of the router fine (i.e. 2001:db8:300:200::2 and 2001:db8:300:201::1).  I *can* ping the ISP gateway from the router though. Is the router not working or have I got something wrong?

Comment: What is with the `/80` prefix? That's wrong; stop what you're doing now. Go back to the ISP and ask them what IPv6 prefix they are delegating to you.

Comment: Please use your real IP addresses. If you must make global routable addresses up, use the documentation prefix of  2001:db8::/32

Comment: @MichaelHampton What information do I need from them? I understand it's usual to have a shorter prefix like /48, but I figured the routing should still work in any case. They've told me the default gateway is 2001:db8:1:1::1 and said the rest of 2001:db8:1:1::/64 subnet is mine. It took them 6 months to set this up and it's actually my landlord who is the client. I want to make sure I understand how it should work before I go back to them since the communication is indirect and the ISP don't appear to understand it either.

Comment: That /64 is only going to be good for that upstream link. They should have routed you a different IPv6 subnet to use for your internal network. This is done automatically with DHCPv6 prefix delegation for residential connections, but it's often a manual setup for business connections. You could probably ask them to use DHCPv6 prefix delegation, or they might already be doing so.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the ISP has given me a /56 prefix now. Would you mind taking a look at the updated question? Thanks for your help.